# Freeze particle emitters in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

On my map, there are many particle emitters all around it. I want to only "process" those emitters that are visible in my iPhone screen.

I could "kill" the emitters when off-screen and re-initialize them when back to screen (or close to it).

But that sounds a bit inefficient. Is there some way to "freeze" particle emitters as in "they don't do anything that consumes more memory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "freeze" or "pause" a particle emitter it will still use the same amount of memory. Killing it is certainly more likely to free up some of the memory used by the particle system.

In any case you could try to pause the particle system's scheduled updates via [CCScheduler](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_scheduler.html):

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] pauseTarget:particleSystem];
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] resumeTarget:particleSystem];
```